# How can i check user really enabled the google voice typing service

Tags: android

i am implementing voice recognize demo, and i want to check if google voice typing service is enabled then open my activity otherwise open language and input setting window, how to apply this condition, help me to achieve this, aarigato in advance

```
Intent intent = new Intent(Intent.ACTION_MAIN);
intent.setClassName("com.android.settings", "com.android.settings.LanguageSettings");            
startActivity(intent);
```

i found this soution to open setting windows but i dont know the condition which i am looking for?..

```
try {
            manager = (LocationManager) getSystemService(Context.LOCATION_SERVICE);
            if (!manager.isProviderEnabled(LocationManager.GPS_PROVIDER)) {
                Intent myIntent = new Intent(Settings.ACTION_LOCATION_SOURCE_SETTINGS);
                startActivity(myIntent);
            } else {
                mapFragment.getMapAsync(this);
            }
        } catch (Exception e) {
            e.printStackTrace();
        }
```

like this one, first i am checking gps is enable or not, if yes then i am opening my map activity.